# Count of rows with values less than or equal to reference rows

Tags: r, count, row

I have a table in which the first 10 rows are the references. For each row in the non-reference rows (i.e. row 11 and beyond), I want to count the number of rows in the reference row (1 to 10) that have a value which is less than or equal to the one in the non-reference row.

```
Row Values
1   1.35
2   0.71
3   1.00
4   0.07
5   0.53
6   0.12
7   0.36
8   2.03
9   3.83
10  1.30
11  2.17
12  1.71
13  1.52
14  1.27
15  0.29
16  0.05
17  0.14
```

The result would look like:

```
Row Values  Count
1   1.35    
2   0.71    
3   1.00    
4   0.07    
5   0.53    
6   0.12    
7   0.36    
8   2.03    
9   3.83    
10  1.30    
11  2.17    9
12  1.71    8
13  1.52    8
14  1.27    6
15  0.29    2
16  0.05    0
17  0.14    2
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a 'Count' column with 'NA' and then replace the elements 11 to the last elements with the output from the `sapply` loop.  We loop the 'Values' 11:17 and check how many reference values are less than or equal than that value. (`sum(df1$Values[1:10] <= x)`)

```
df1$Count <- NA
df1$Count[11:nrow(df1)] <- sapply(df1$Values[11:nrow(df1)], 
         function(x) sum(df1$Values[1:10] <= x))
df1$Count
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  9  8  8  6  2  0  2
```

Or instead of a loop, we can also use `findInterval`

```
df1$Count[11:nrow(df1)] <-  findInterval(df1$Values[11:nrow(df1)], 
                         sort(df1$Values[1:10]))
```